How do I configure UART clock settings in vivado for the Zynq7 PS and make sure it is exported properly to hardware?
I want to modify the clocks in the zynq 7000 PS for a peripheral, e.g. the UART, so I can operate one of the UART's at a desired baud rate. I wanted to set the UART clock for 80MHz in the Zynq 7000 PS (it is 100MHz by default) but the changes that I make in Vivado do not seem to be getting exported properly.
I attempted to change it to 80MHz in my Vivado block design first; then, make changes to UART0 registers in the application software (CD and BDIV) to modify to an arbitrary baud rate and verify the clock was changed to the expected 80MHz. I.e., I tried the following:

Open Zynq7 PS block by double clicking it.

Go to Clock Configuration (Advanced Clocking tab).

Click "Override Clocks" and change the IOPLL multiplier to 16 (this made the IOPLL Freq 800MHz with input freq of 50MHz).

Set the UART clock source to IO PLL and its first divisor to 20 (this caused 80 to show in the "Actual Frequency(MHz)" field). I want this UART clock to be at 80MHz.

Set any other component clocks that may be out of range [because of the new PLL multiplier] to a frequency that put them in range by modifying their divisors.

Click ok on the block settings for the zynq PS and noted several "set property" settings in the Tcl console.

Validated design->create HDL wrapper->generate bitstream->export hardware.

Switch over to my vitis application software and go to my platform and switch the "Hardware Design (XSA) For Implementation" to the new exported hardware (.xsa) file.

Build my platform.

Create a simple "Hello world" application and add the following lines of code to test changing of baud rate:


    #define UART0_BAUDGEN_OFFSET  0x18    // Offset for CD (Baud Rate Generator)
    #define UART0_BAUDDIV_OFFSET  0x34    // Offset for BDIV (Baud Rate Divider)
        
    void main(){
    
    // Set the CD (Clock Divider) in the Baud Rate Generator register
    Xil_Out32(XPAR_UART0_BASEADDR + UART0_BAUDGEN_OFFSET, 10);
    
    // Set the BDIV (Baud Rate Divider) in the Baud Rate Divider register
    Xil_Out32(XPAR_UART0_BASEADDR + UART0_BAUDDIV_OFFSET, 7);
    
    // main loop with delay and print hello world...
    }

The baud rate setting here for UART0 is expected to be 1MHz with a 80MHz clock. However, after building the code, running it, and recording the "Hello World" result with a serial terminal, the baud rate is actually confirmed to be at 1.25MHz (because the clock to the UART never changed to 80MHz and is still at 100MHz). I am assuming baud rate is defined as $$BaudRate = \frac{\text{UART_CLK_FREQ}}{(CD\times(BDIV+1))}$$
Am I missing some crucial step or going about this wrong? How do I get these clock changes in Vivado (in the zynq PS) to go into effect? I appreciate any help or advice with this issue. Thank you.

I was able to change the clocks for the IOPLL and UART peripheral by manually configuring their control registers in software. E.g. by changing the PLL_FDIV in the IO_PLL_CTRL register. Note: before changing the PLL_FDIV, you first have to enable writes to the slcr registers by writing the unlock code to SLCR_UNLOCK, then enable bypass and reset the IOPLL in the IO_PLL_CTRL register. The issue of why the clock changes in Vivado are not exporting properly to hardware is still unknown to me though.
